# react-hot-loader.development.js?9cb3:2375 React-Hot-Loader: react--dom patch is not detected. React 16.6+ features may not work

Tags: reactjs, react-hot-loader

```
react-hot-loader.development.js?9cb3:2375 React-Hot-Loader: react--dom patch is not detected. React 16.6+ features may not work.
```

**My react version `"react": "^16.12.0",**`

and

```
 "react-hot-loader": "^4.12.19",
```

Any solution for this?

Comment: What is your React-Hot-Loader version? I think this can happen if they are mismatched, either in the package.json or the lockfile.

Comment: Hi, i updated the question        "react-hot-loader": "^4.12.19",

Answer (score 0):

The previous (v16.11 and lower) solution to this was to install [`@hot-loader/react-dom`](https://github.com/hot-loader/react-dom) aliased as react-dom for development. However, no new versions of this will be forthcoming, for reasons to do with that... IDK, Abramov doesn't want to do it that way? But no other solutions have been given either. At any rate, it appears for now you have to make do and hope we don't run into any bugs.

Dissatisfying, to be sure.